How to run a statistical test to look for over-enrichment of specific genes, across three different phenotypes, row wise?

This is my contingency_table:
Gene_group  phenotype1  phenotype2  phenotype3
Gene_group1 2   4   26
Gene_group2 0   0   1
Gene_group3 2   6   4
Gene_group4 1   0   0
Gene_group5 0   0   2
Gene_group6 0   0   1
Gene_group7 0   0   1
Gene_group8 0   1   1
Gene_group9 3   0   6
Gene_group10    0   0   1

I want to identify gene groups that are significantly enriched in one phenotype over the other two individual phenotypes.
To do this, I want to see if the distribution of phenotypes in each gene group differs significantly from the distribution in the remaining ST groups. I then want to see if phenotype1 or phenotype3 is associated with a specific ST group.
Am I right in thinking that I need to run a Fisher's exact test, in a row wise manner, using a 3x2 matrix for each gene group? For each gene group I want to add a new column for the p-value. Do I then need an additional column for the multiple testing corrected p-value perhaps using the Bonferroni correction?
When i say 3x2 matrix, I think each gene group's data can be represented in a 3x2 matrix format, where:

Columns: Represent the three phenotype categories (phenotype1, phenotype2, phenotype3)
Rows: Two rows represent the counts for the gene group being tested and the counts for the remaining gene groups.

To do this I've tried the following:
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Create contingency table as a data frame
contingency_table <- data.frame(
  Gene_group = c("Gene_group1", "Gene_group2", "Gene_group3", "Gene_group4", "Gene_group5", "Gene_group6", "Gene_group7", "Gene_group8", "Gene_group9", "Gene_group10"),
  phenotype1 = c(2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0),
  phenotype2 = c(4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  phenotype3 = c(26, 1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1)
)

# Function to run Fisher's exact test for each Gene group
run_fisher_test <- function(gene_group_row, total_counts) {
  # Extract the counts for the current Gene group
  current_counts <- as.numeric(gene_group_row[2:4])
  
  # Counts for the remaining groups
  remaining_counts <- colSums(total_counts[-which(total_counts$Gene_group == gene_group_row$Gene_group), 2:4])
  
  # Create the contingency table
  contingency_matrix <- rbind(current_counts, remaining_counts)
  
  # Run Fisher's exact test
  test_result <- fisher.test(contingency_matrix)
  
  return(test_result$p.value)
}

# Apply the function to each row of the contingency table
contingency_table <- contingency_table %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(p_value = run_fisher_test(cur_data(), contingency_table)) %>%
  ungroup()  # Ungroup after rowwise operations

# Total number of tests
num_tests <- nrow(contingency_table)

# Adjust p-values using Bonferroni correction
contingency_table <- contingency_table %>%
  mutate(adjusted_p_value = p.adjust(p_value, method = "bonferroni")) %>%
  mutate(bonferroni_significance = 0.05 / num_tests)  # Calculate the Bonferroni significance level

# View the results
print(contingency_table)

The results look like this:

Does all of this sounds like the correct method?
I then also want to run a 2 x 2 Fishers exact test to look at gene groups significantly enriched in either phenotype1 or phenotype3, adding the p-value and multiple testing corrected p-value to additional columns for each gene group.
I'm new to coding in R, so any advice would be very helpful please.

It is not clear what your Unit under Test (UUT) is here? Is it the 3 phenotypes, or the 10 gene-groups? Are you trying to find differences between phenotypes, as represented by 10 gene groups, or between gene groups, as expressed accross 3 phenotypes? Could you edit your question, and make this point very clear? From your answer, we can then assess what contingency matrices you should consider... Thanks

I want to see if the distribution of phenotypes in each gene group differs significantly from the distribution in the remaining ST groups. I then want to see if phenotype1 or phenotype3 is associated with specific ST groups.

The first thing I would do is run a 3x10 contingency table, using Fisher-exact (typically, the units under test -aka groups- are the columns, and the rows are the various categories; the results are exactlky the same if one transposes the matrix, but, tradition...). ($\chi^2$ will have troubles with all the 0's and 1's, hence Fisher). This is an omnibus test, which will tell you if all your groups are more or less expressed similarly accross the 3 phenotypes, or not. I think we can guess the answer here (no, group1 is different).
Then I would run a series of 3x2 tables, to compare pairs of gene groups. Since you have 10 groups, you would have 45 such comparisons. But just looking at the data, it seems clear that group1 is the only which has a chance to be significantly different from all the other groups. So I would reduce the comparisons to only 9 (group1 against all the others, 1 by 1, not combined).
You should use a multiple comparison correction (Sidak?) for these 9 tests (45 tests would really affect your power).
